# Bitcoin core, wallet is empty?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core

So I have a bitcoin core wallet. And I bought bitcoins and filled out the address under, I think the english word for it is: reception addresses. [image] see picture. I assumed this was my wallet address. Everything went well with the transaction. I can see there is send money to this address. But my wallet is still empty after 4 hours. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your bitcoins will appear when you're done synchronizing. Bitcoin Core first has to catch up with 4 years of transaction history before it can verify current transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Your client is currently unaware of the transaction on the bitcoin network because it is not synced with the bitcoin network.  Wait for the green progress bar at the bottom of the client to complete.  Once your client is aware of the transaction it will show your appropriate balance.